# Rotativa PDF generation failure and web farm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I'm using both the ViewAsPDF and ActionAsPDF methods at different parts of the website and have deployed the code to our production servers.  When I access the individual server IP addresses then the PDF's print as expected but when I use the URL which is load balanced across the servers, the PDF functionality fails with the following error:

```
Exception information:
    Exception type: Exception
    Exception message: Error: Failed loading page http://example.com/PDF (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError

   at Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches, String html)
   at Rotativa.WkhtmltopdfDriver.Convert(String wkhtmltopdfPath, String switches)
   at Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.CallTheDriver(ControllerContext context)
   at Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.BuildPdf(ControllerContext context)
   at Rotativa.AsPdfResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

A common solution to PDF generation is to add the msvcp120.dll and msvcr120.dll files to the same folder as wkhtmltopdf.exe but this hasn't made a difference.